# Auto add place to a form field by GEO location AMP-HTML conform

Tags: geolocation, amp-html

Is there a way to add place to a form field by GEO location? It should be an AMP-HTML solution or a solution without JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by rendering the form via amp-list. You can determine the GEO location based on the amp-list's src request (which is not cached) and then include the location in the returned JSON response. Inside the amp-list's mustache template you then can simply render the form with the correct location using the JSON response.

Comment: I understand now how to get list data but not how to get and transform the GEO Data into the city list without JS. There is an open issue about this topic on Github: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/826

Comment: You have to handle this server-side. The server has to filter the cities before returning them via JSON.